# How can I pinch to change icon size in OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, mac, finder, osx-mountain-lion

Recently I upgraded from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion. SL had this nice slider in the finder you could use to change icon sizes really easily. I also remember being able to use the Magic Trackpad and pinch / unpinch to be able to change the icon size.

Now in ML this slider is missing and my pinch / unpinch no longer works. How can I get these things back?

[image: screenshoton20090212at1048ampng749b9.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ML's Finder, click on View / Show Status Bar, or just use ⌘/ to toggle. The slider should now be visible. Unfortunately, it seems they did away with the pinch/unpinch actions.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution.
Go to
`View` > `Show status bar`.

And you have the wonderful slider back.

Answer (score 0):

To re-enable the Pinch to Zoom feature in the OS X Finder, install PathFinder 6 through version 6.1.5 ONLY from Cocoatech.  Later versions of PathFinder no longer have this feature anymore either! Then, use PathFinder instead of the Finder and Pinch to Zoom is BACK!!!

Sincerely,

Erikthefinn